# Assign single space to variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I want to have a variable which is basicaly a space or any empty character. Which would allow me to display an empty table such as:

```
#########
#       #
#       #
#       #
#########
```

but all I can get is:

```
#########
##
##
##
#########
```

Is there any sort of special character which would do what I need? I was looking around and I saw that you can assign BackSpace to a variable but thats it. Maybe I am bad at searching but I couldnt find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Updated code , which will do the required

```
@echo off
set a=######
set b=#
set "c= "
echo %a%
echo %b%%c%%c%%c%%c%%b%
echo %b%%c%%c%%c%%c%%b%
echo %b%%c%%c%%c%%c%%b%
echo %b%%c%%c%%c%%c%%b%
echo %a%
pause
```

If you want a bigger table then it would take a bit for typing so, we can use loops

Try Below Code

```
@echo off
set a=######
set b=#
set "c= "
for /L %%j in (1,1,1) do (
echo %a%
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 5) do ( echo %b%%c%%c%%c%%c%%b%)
echo %a%
)
pause
```

Comment: This will work but I need to have every character assigned so having 
`"#     #"` doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: @Hoffs try the updated code , assigned every character to a variable to suit your requirement

Answer (score 2):

The variable needs to be delimited. This can be done by using quotes.

```
SET "ASPACE= "
```

Comment: But it still doesn't work @Liturgist . Heres my code: http://pastebin.com/b1f4XjnX and the result I get still is `##`

Comment: Please put the code into Stackoverflow. I cannot access to pastebin.com.

Answer (score 2):

You can use " " to achieve this

```
set "x= "
```

Comment: Does it? @carton32  
  
`set "x= "  
echo|set /p =#  
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 12) do (  
  echo|set /p =%x%  
  )  
echo|set/p =#`   
I still get same result:  
`##`

Answer (score 2):

`set /p` eats leading spaces. Might this fit your needs?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "x=" 
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 12) do set "x=!x! " 
echo ##############
echo #%x%#
echo #%x%#
echo ##############
```

this assembles the string of spaces *before* echoing it.

Alternative:

```
@echo off
set "x=                                     "
echo #%x:~0,12%#
```

this takes a substring of the desired length out of a long string of spaces (should be much quicker)

If you want to be more flexible:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "spaces=                                           " 
set "border=###########################################"
set len=12

echo #!border:~0,%len%!#
echo #!spaces:~0,%len%!#
echo #!spaces:~0,3!Hello.!spaces:~0,3!#
echo #!spaces:~0,%len%!#
echo #!border:~0,%len%!#
```